# Run a K3S server in a docker container, and connect a K3S agent in another docker container

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, k3d

I know `k3d` can do this magically via `k3d cluster create myname --token MYTOKEN --agents 1`, but I am trying to figure out how to do the most simple version of that 'manually'. I want to create a server something like:

```
 docker run -e K3S_TOKEN=MYTOKEN rancher/k3s:latest server
```

And connect an agent something like like:

```
 docker run -e K3S_TOKEN=MYTOKEN -e K3S_URL=https://localhost:6443 rancher/k3s:latest agent
```

Does anyone know what ports need to be forwarded here? How can I set this up? Nearly everything I try, the agent complains about port 6444 already in use, even if I disable as much as possible about the server with any combination of `--no-deploy servicelb --disable-agent --no-deploy traefik`

Feel free to disable literally everything other than the server and the agent, I'm trying to make this ultra ultra simple, but just butting my head against a wall at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The containers must "see" each other. Docker isolates the networks by default, so "localhost" in your agent container is the agent container itself.

Possible solutions:
Run both containers without network isolation using `--net=host`, map API port of the server to the host with `--port` and use the host IP in the agent container or use docker-compose.

A working example for docker-compose is described here: https://www.trion.de/news/2019/08/28/kubernetes-in-docker-mit-k3s.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Using the example .yaml, I can start the cluster. But I'm trying to replicate what the docker-compose does with individual containers via `docker run`. For example, I can start the server with docker-compose, but then if I want to add an agent (via `docker run --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /var/run --privileged -e K3S_CLUSTER_SECRET=somethingtotallyrandom -e K3S_URL=https://server:6443 rancher/k3s:latest` which matches the worker config in the .yaml), it is unable to connect due to `failed to get CA certs: Get \"https://127.0.0.1:6444/cacerts\`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, I think I've got it! The docker-compose was implicitly starting a network for the containers defined within it. If I do `docker network create NAME` and then in my `docker run` commands I include the `--network NAME` parameter, they are now able to find eachother based on hostnames. So I can start as many agents as I like within this network! So I think I've solved it. Thanks for the link, that docker-compose.yaml was crucial

Comment: Glad, that it helped, please accept the answer in that case.

Comment: @ricky116, can you please post your full invocation of both the server and the agent (master and worker)?

Comment: Here's mine: `sudo docker run --rm -it --net=k3s-home --privileged -e K3S_CLUSTER_SECRET=somethingtotallyrandom --hostname master  rancher/k3s:latest server` and then `sudo docker run --rm -it --net=k3s-home --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /var/run --privileged -e K3S_TOKEN=somethingtotallyrandom -e K3S_URL=https://master:6443 --hostname worker rancher/k3s:latest agent --token <token>`. I've got the <token> by doing a `docker exec -it <server> sh` and then `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/node-token`. I'm pretty sure this can be automated.